# one js file for calculations

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, equation

i have a js file (which utilises the jquery framework) that is a simple equation to calculate corresponding values.

JS FILE (sample):

```
var colorOneRed = parseFloat($('#colorOneRed').text()); ...

var totalRed = (parseFloat(colorOneRed) + parseFloat(colorTwoRed) ...

$('#totalColorRed').text(totalRed); ...
```

I have the same exact equation multiple times, only the color changes. So the same equation is used for green `var colorGreen`, blue, purple, etc.

My question is can I write just the one equation to encompass all the variables and `#id's`
instead writing the same equation over and over.

I tried the `id^='totalcolor'` method for example, but it will only calculate the one variable. So what I mean is, if `#colorOneRed` has a value of `40` but `#colorOneGreen` has a value of `60` it will only calculate the one value for all using the `id^=colorOne` method.

I'm not sure its even possible but i'm hoping to have one equation that will be able to have a calculation for all the `greens` and one for all the `blues` and so on.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I did not clearly understand the question. But after reading twice, I feel like you are dealing with a very simple problem which requires `function`alize the code and send elements `($("element id"))` as parameters to those functions.

Comment: Please show a sample of your html. This is probably pretty easy to do with your current structure, but it might be easier still with a small change to add a class here or there. As an aside, you don't need to use `parseFloat()` on something that is already a number. Use it on the `.text()` value, sure, but you don't then need to use it again on the `colorOneRed` variable which already holds a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to do. Checkout this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/niranjan_borawake/dLY6z/1/). You can always extend this for other `color` elements.

Comment: Thanks. That was exactly what I was trying to achieve.

Comment: Welcome. But I would suggest you to add proper `classes` to elements that you want to query e.g. `red`, `blue`, instead of writing a complex `ID` based `selector`.

Comment: I'm a little confused. So if I change for example `id="colorOneRed"` to `class="colorOne Red"` how would alter the equation and/or make it simpler and less complicated?

Comment: Could you put your code here, instead of making us go to a different site that may one day not be there?

Comment: @Teepeemm Actually putting code somewhere like [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) increases its validness and its easy to make some changes and try them out. But I do take your point as well, yes, if the code is of few lines it should be fine to replicate it in the answer post as well.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your code in a function where you pass in the required DOM elements to perform the calculation:

```
function calculate(colorOneElement, totalElement) {

    var colorOne = parseFloat($(colorOneElement).text()); ...

    var total = (parseFloat(colorOneRed) + parseFloat(colorTwoRed) ...

    $(totalElemenet).text(totalRed); ...

}
```

The use as follows:

```
calculate(document.getElementById("colorOneRed"),
        document.getElementById("totalOneRed"));

calculate(document.getElementById("colorOneGreen"),
        document.getElementById("totalOneGreen"));
```

etc ...

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just pass the ids to the function and use `getElementById()` within the function?

Comment: true - but hopefully the OP gets the idea - that they need to turn this into a function.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was a little confused at first when trying to test out your code on existing work, but I managed to get it to work. I went with Niranjan solution however, as I was able to join it to my existing code a lot smoother. Thank You again for providing a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Put the calculation in one function:

```
function calc(displayElt, color){
var total=parseFloat($('#colorOne'+color).text()) + parseFloat($('#colorTwo'+color).text())+..
$('#'+displayElt).text(total);
}

calc(totalColorRed,Red);
```

Comment: Thank You for the help, I decided to go with Niranjan method as when I tested it out it seemed to work on all and was easier to implement into my already existing code.